# Error connecting Node.js + MongoDB application within Docker containers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker-compose, timeout, s

Error connecting Node.js + MongoDB application within Docker containers
I have a Node.js + MongoDB application that works perfectly without Docker. However, when I containerize it using Docker Compose, I encounter an error related to the timeout:

> kinopoisk-node-app-1  | MongooseError: Operation `genres.count()`
> buffering timed out after 10000ms kinopoisk-node-app-1  |     at
> Timeout.
> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:23)
> kinopoisk-node-app-1  |     at listOnTimeout
> (node:internal/timers:569:17) kinopoisk-node-app-1  |     at
> process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
> kinopoisk-node-app-1  |  kinopoisk-node-app-1  | Node.js v18.14.2
> kinopoisk-node-app-1 exited with code 1

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.14.2

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8000

CMD node server.js
```

docker-compose.yml:

```yml
version: '3'
services:
  node-app:
    build: .
    image: kinopoisk:0.0.1
    ports:
      - 8080:8000
    environment:
      - MONGO_ADDRESS=mongodb://mongodb:27017/kinopoisk
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.4.6-bionic
```

Node.js connection code:

```node
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_ADDRESS).then(() => {
    return console.log("Connected to mongoDB")
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log("Failed to connect to mongoDB")
})
```

Seed file:

```node
const genres = require('./genres')
const data = [
    'Комедии',
    'Мультфильмы',
    'Ужасы',
    'Фантастика',
    'Триллеры',
    'Боевики',
    'Мелодрамы',
    'Детективы',
    'Приключения',
    'Фэнтези',
] 

async function writeDataGenre(){
    const length = await genres.count();
    if(length==0){
        data.map((item, index) => {
            new genres({
                name: item,
                key: index
            }).save()
        })
    }
}

module.exports = writeDataGenre
```

I expect the Node.js application to successfully connect to the MongoDB server within the Docker container without encountering the connection timeout error.